# How to review GitLab "Merge Requests" locally with WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, gitlab, webstorm, merge-request

GitLab has [VSCode extension](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/03/01/gitlab-vscode-extension/) for reviewing merge requests. I wonder if there is some way to achieve this in WebStorm?

Cheers!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [GitLab Projects 2020](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14110-gitlab-projects-2020/) that provides Merge Request review functionality.

Native support in the IDE is not available at the moment. Feel free to follow [IDEA-109294](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109294).